# problem with reference to nodes in a matrix

Tags: c, pointers, reference, null

i going to try to explain all the code that i will put in the  next parts, first i going to tell you the problem, i am losing the reference of a pointer in  this matrix that conect one node with her neighbour, i put a printf to you to help to see what kind of lost of refence i am having, now the program i  am tring to make is a matrix that contain nodes that in his  atribute had the neighbour up,down,left,right and i am tring to prevent the edge case putting null pointers in the neighbour attribute, but i dont know why isn t work right, because the null change suddenly for 1 and i realy dont know why.
here is the code:(this is the smaller code that i could do for show the error)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int id;  
    int col;
    int row;
    int node_restricted; 
    struct Node* up;
    struct Node* down;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    int color;

}Node;
Node init_node(int id,int col, int row){
    Node new_node;
    new_node.id=id;
    new_node.col = col;
    new_node.row = row;
    new_node.up = NULL;
    new_node.down = NULL;
    new_node.left = NULL;
    new_node.right = NULL;
    new_node.color = 0;
    new_node.node_restricted = 0;

    return new_node;
}
Node** form_matrix_with_node(int amount_of_node_axis_x,int amount_of_node_axis_y){

    Node** matrix_with_node = calloc(amount_of_node_axis_x,sizeof(Node*));

    for (int i = 0; i < amount_of_node_axis_x; i++)
    {
        matrix_with_node[i] = calloc(amount_of_node_axis_y,sizeof(Node));
    }
    
    
    int total_of_node = amount_of_node_axis_x*amount_of_node_axis_y;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < total_of_node; i++)
    {
        if (((col+1)%amount_of_node_axis_x)==0)
        {
            matrix_with_node[row][col] = init_node(i,row,col);
            row = row + 1; 
            col = 0;
        }else{
            matrix_with_node[row][col] = init_node(i,row,col);
            col = col + 1;    
        }
        
    }
    
    link_between_node(matrix_with_node,amount_of_node_axis_x,amount_of_node_axis_y);
    matrix_with_node[0][0].color = 1;
    matrix_with_node[0][2].color = 1;
    matrix_with_node[0][3].color = 1;
    printf("this is my left pointer  %d\n",matrix_with_node[1][0].left);
    matrix_with_node[0][4].color = 1;
    printf("this is my left pointer  %d\n",matrix_with_node[1][0].left);
    matrix_with_node[1][0].color = 1;
    matrix_with_node[1][1].color = 1;
    matrix_with_node[1][2].color = 1;
    matrix_with_node[2][0].color = 1;
    matrix_with_node[3][0].color = 2; 
    
    
    

    
    return matrix_with_node;
}

void link_between_node(Node** matrix_with_node,int amount_of_node_axis_x,int amount_of_node_axis_y){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < amount_of_node_axis_x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < amount_of_node_axis_y; j++)
        {            
            //en el siguente se ve si la conexion con el nodo de arriba
            if ((i-1)>=0)
            {            
                matrix_with_node[i][j].up = &(matrix_with_node[i-1][j]);
            }//en el siguente se ve si la conexion con el nodo de abajo
            if ((i+1)<amount_of_node_axis_y)
            {                
                matrix_with_node[i][j].down = &(matrix_with_node[i+1][j]);
            }//en el siguente se ve si la conexion con el nodo de izquierda
            if ((j-1)>=0)
            {                
                matrix_with_node[i][j].left = &(matrix_with_node[i][j-1]);
            }//en el siguente se ve si la conexion con el nodo de derecha
            if ((j+1)<amount_of_node_axis_x)
            {
                matrix_with_node[i][j].right = &(matrix_with_node[i][j+1]);
            }
        }      
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    form_matrix_with_node(4,4);
}
```

Comment: One problem is that if you are allocating 4 elements, you can't assign the element at index 4. i.e. `matrix_with_node[0][4].color = 1;` requires at least 5 elements.

Comment: If you have that many pointers in your node struct, maybe you wont need a matrix?

Comment: wildplasser yes i know, but a need the matrix to do the pointer :D

Comment: thanks EdmCoff that was the problem, i didn t see that the matrix was more smaller :D